# Extract (price data as) 1D vector from nested cell

Tags: matlab, cell-array, data-extraction

Given:

```
data = { ...
    { '2014-12-31'    [79.2100] }  ...
    { '2014-12-30'    [79.3000] }  ...
    { '2014-12-26'    [79.1200] }  };
```

I need to extract:

```
prices = [ 79.2100, 79.3000, 79.1200 ];
```

What is a good way to accomplish this?  A `for` loop would be simple to implement, and combined with pre-allocation would be reasonably efficient. But it looks a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first convert your cell array to *not* a nested array and then extract the second column and convert from a cell to an array to a normal array using `cat` combined with `{}` indexing.

```
% Turn your nested cell array into an N x 2 cell array
data = cat(1, data{:});

% Get just the second column
prices = cat(2, data{:,2});
```